# Identifying matrix vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following question in a book:

[image: Question from book]

According to the book, the answer is **(D)**. But I don't understand how. Isn't this just scalar multiplication? The solution in the book says that I have to use determinants. How do I work this one out? Is the book wrong? (No?).

Comment: Hint: what if you were doing co-factors to find the determinant, what would it look like? The book is right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $B$ is equal to the *determinant* of the second matrix; $A$ is equal to the *determinant* of the first matrix. Have you tried computing the determinant of each to see that we get B = 27A?

***A is not a matrix, B is not the matrix***.

We do have that the matrix for which the determinant equals B, call it $B_M = 3 A_M$, where $A_M$ is the matrix whose determinant is equal to A. But, $\det B_M = 3^3 \det A_M$

Recall, that when finding the determinant of a matrix, if a *row* of one matrix is multiplied by a scalar $c$, then the determinant $B$ of the resulting matrix $ 3\det A$: for EACH row. Here, you have *three rows* in the second matrix that are each a multiple of a row in the first matrix, hence we have $$ B = 3\cdot 3\cdot 3 A = 3^3 A = 27 A$$

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but why isn't this scalar multiplication?

Comment: $\det? \cdot? what??

Comment: Note that $B$ is equal to the determinant of the second matrix; $A$ is equal to the determinant of the first matrix. Have you tried computing the determinant of each to see that we get B = 27A? A is not a matrix, B is not the matrix. We do have that the Matrix for which the determinant equals B, call it $B_M = 3 A_M$, where $A_M$ is the matrix whose determinant is equal to A. But, $\det B_M = 3^3 \det A_M$

Comment: Thanks you, but my real question was "Why isn't this scalar multiplication?". Vadim answered that question. Thanks anyway :) !

Comment: I'm sorry, I did answer that in the comment...I explained why it isn't scalar multiplication.

Comment: Boy I don't know which to select as the right answer!

Comment: I'm just trying to help! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Deserves another thumbs up! +1

Answer (score 2):

The vertical bars denote determinant.  They are not just placeholders to hold the matrix, like square brackets or parentheses.

Comment: Problem solved :) ! Thanks!